# Is there a way to parametrise an animation?

Tags: android, xml, animation

I've created a simple animation to make a view move up and down repeatedly:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="???"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:repeatCount="1000000"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"/>
</set>
```

I'm using an animation resource for that like it is suggested in the docs. However, at compile time I don't know how far down the view is supposed to go (`toYDelta`) as it will depend on the device screen.

Is there a way to parametrise that somehow and if not, what would be a way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the same animation programmatically like that in Kotlin:

```
val bounceAnimation = TranslateAnimation(0f, 0f, fromYDelta, toYDelta).apply {
    duration = 1000
    repeatCount = 1000000
    repeatMode = Animation.REVERSE
    interpolator = AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()
}

view.startAnimation(bounceAnimation)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can express those Values as Percentage, eg. : "20%p" is 20% of the parent

See for more info
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource

Answer (score 1):

Documentation says [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource):

> A vertical and/or horizontal motion. Supports the following attributes in any of the following three formats: values from -100 to 100 ending with "%", indicating a percentage relative to itself; values from -100 to 100 ending in "%p", indicating a percentage relative to its parent; a float value with no suffix, indicating an absolute value. Represents a TranslateAnimation.

`%p` will help you do what you want.